# Add field to layer in QGIS using Python in a plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, fields-attributes

I'm trying to write a plugin for QGIS that adds a field to a layer selected from a combobox and calculates area.

For that I import these modules:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant, QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QIcon, QFileDialog
```

and in the run function:

```
def run(self):
    # here I populate a combo box in a form
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list = []
    for layer in layers:
        layer_list.append(layer.name())
    self.dlg.Cmb_Capa.addItems(layer_list)

    self.dlg.show()
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    if result:
```

Now here comes my problem... I find this in the documentation page of QGIS to add a field to a layer

```
if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddAttributes:
    res = layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("mytext", QVariant.String), QgsField("myint", QVariant.Int)])
```

but I don't know how to take the layer selected in the combo and apply this.

Can anyone give me a hand or a tip about how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method (which you are currently using) is the standard [QComboBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html). First we need to import some more classes so add this before importing PyQt4:

```
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsField, QgsExpression
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant, QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication
```

Then in your `run(self)` function, we can use the following (I've added some comments which hopefully will help you understand what's going on):

```
def run(self):
    # here I populate a combo box in a form
    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list = []
    for layer in layers:
        layer_list.append(layer.name())
    self.dlg.Cmb_Capa.addItems(layer_list)

    self.dlg.show()
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    if result:
        # Read current text from combo box
        combo_layer = self.dlg.Cmb_Capa.currentText()
        # Identify layer from table of contents by matching name with the combo box text
        selected_layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(combo_layer)[0]
        # Add a "real" field type with the name "Area"
        selected_layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("Area", QVariant.Double) ] )
        # Update the attribute table
        selected_layer.updateFields()
        # Allow editing of the selected layer
        selected_layer.startEditing()
        # Find index of the newly-created "Area" field
        idx = selected_layer.fieldNameIndex( "Area" )
        # Use standard QgsExpression to calculate area for each feature
        e = QgsExpression( """ $area """ )
        e.prepare( selected_layer.pendingFields() )
        for f in selected_layer.getFeatures():
            f[idx] = e.evaluate(f)
            selected_layer.updateFeature(f)
        # Save the selected layer
        selected_layer.commitChanges()
```

---

Alternatively, you could use QGIS custom widget: [QgsMapLayerComboBox](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayerComboBox.html). This is **automatically** updated when any changes are made to the layer list (i.e. layers added/removed, names changed etc) without you having to refresh the plugin. To use this, you will need to import an additional class:

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapLayerProxyModel
```

Now your `run(self)` function can look like this:

```
 def run(self):
    # Here, QgsMapLayerComboBox automatically reads the relevant layers
    self.dlg.Cmb_Capa.setFilters( QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PolygonLayer )

    self.dlg.show()
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    if result:
        combo_layer = self.dlg.Cmb_Capa.currentText()
        selected_layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(combo_layer)[0]
        selected_layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("Area", QVariant.Double) ] )
        selected_layer.updateFields()
        selected_layer.startEditing()
        idx = selected_layer.fieldNameIndex( "Area" )
        e = QgsExpression( """ $area """ )
        e.prepare( selected_layer.pendingFields() )
        for f in selected_layer.getFeatures():
            f[idx] = e.evaluate(f)
            selected_layer.updateFeature(f)
        selected_layer.commitChanges()
```

Note: When using QGIS custom widgets, you may need to edit your *"plugin_name_dialog_base.ui"* file, find the `QgsMapLayerComboBox class` and replace the `<header>` to qgis.gui.h.

For example, it might look like this:

```
<customwidget>
 <class>QgsMapLayerComboBox</class>
 <extends>QComboBox</extends>
 <header>qgsmaplayercombobox.h</header>
</customwidget>
```

And it needs to look like this:

```
<customwidget>
 <class>QgsMapLayerComboBox</class>
 <extends>QComboBox</extends>
 <header>qgis.gui.h</header>
</customwidget>
```